# How to get the string value in each loop in thymeleaf and apply it to a date field in a modal with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

My application consists of an event calendar. In thymeleaf the month days are retrieved in a each loop as a Map from the controller, whose key is the day as String and value the content of the user for that day- but the content is irrelevant here, only the key. The calendar has a box for each key, which the user can click. When the user clicks it, the  link with class '.nBtn' opens a (Bootstrap modal box) with a date-type field for the user to set the date. I'd like to open the modal with date set for the day clicked is showed in the date field but I don't know how to access the key from the each loop in thymeleaf. How to get that eachDay.key to populate the date field in the modal when the user clicks the respective date in the calendar? Could you please help?

Note: I cannot retrieve a model from the controller because this object is created only after the user clicks the submit button in the modal. Therefore, there's no object in the db yet to retrieve.

```
<div class="days">
   <div class="day-cell button" th:each="eachDay : ${daysOfTheMonth}">

        <a class="nBtn">
           <input type="hidden" id="eachday" value="${eachDay.key}" />

           <span class="round-day" th:text="${#strings.substring(eachDay.key,8)}"></span>
           <span class="day-content" th:text="${eachDay.value}"></span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- /day-cell -->
</div> <!-- /days -->
                        </div> <!-- /calendar -->

<div class="myForm">
    <form th:action="@{/eventController/saveEvent}" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-abelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Verfügbar werden</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date" class="col-form-label">Datum:</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control mb-10 col-6" id="date" name="date" value="" />
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Speichern" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.nBtn').on('click',function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
        });                     

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign custom arguments to `a.nBtn` which can be accessed in jQuery code and assigned to form elements. Something like:

```
<a class="nBtn" th:args="data-day=${eachDay.key}"> 
 <!-- Other HTML -->
</a>
```

In Javascript:

```
$('.nBtn').on('click',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var day = $(evt).data('day');
    //TODO: You will have to format the day into a format accepted by input type date.
    $("#date").val(day)
    $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
});
```

Note: 
- Ensure that you format the day into the format accepted by `input type='date'`
- Ensure that the id you are generating for your hidden element `#eachday` is unique. If you want that to be submitted to the server as form data you can have the same name, but better to maintain different id.

Comment: Thank you very much Mohamed, it helped a loooot. I had to remove the th:args="" because I was getting an error that the page could not be rendered. But leaving the remaining together with an id I could access it from the jquery code you provided. What was the reason for th:args="" instead of just the rest?

Comment: if u can share the exception stack trace that will help me. Mostly there would have been some syntax error.